# How does a router setup as a dumb switch work?

Tags: router, dhcp, switch

If you disable DHCP on a router ("router A") and connect an ethernet cable to one of its ports (from another router, "router b"), router A becomes a dumb switch.

But how does this work? How does the router now know where to send its packets?

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the switch ports and disable DHCP, no TCP/IP packets will be sent by clients to the address of the router.

You can think of your router as containing several separated devices that operate somewhat independently

[image]

A typical SOHO "router" incoroporates a 4-port ethernet switch. This works in the usual way a dumb ethernet switch works even when all the other parts of the box are sitting idle with nothing to do.

A router only does routing if it receives an ethernet packet that has a destination MAC address matching the router's MAC address and where the ethernet packet encapsulates an IP-packet with an off-LAN IP-address.

Two PCs communicating with each other via the ethernet-switch part will only create ethernet packets with each-others MAC address as the destination, not with the routers MAC address as destination.

Answer (score 0):

If the router is now acting as switch, think of it like a surge protector. You can plug multiple devices needing power into it, but it still only draws power from 1 source.

Well a switch is like that, lets assume your router b was the modem from isp, well unless its strictly a modem and not a modem/router combo box, it will have 1 ethernet port. Also lets assume you don't need routing functions such as NAT as all you want to do is just connect them to the internet but don't care about having a device helping you communicate with the other devices. A switch has a bunch of ethernet ports to connect the systems to it, and then 1 ethernet port, to connect a cable to the modem.

Now you have effectively multiplied the modems ethernet port to more than 1. That is the function of the switch, and the reason the switch will work, has to do with how devices on any network communicate with each other without knowing each other. There is a reason why all network interfaces have Mac addresses. This Mac address is very useful in getting packets to the right device. So instead of router A doing routing, Router B does the routing instead as all router A is doing, is just forwarding the packets according to destination MAC.

Also to clarify, just because you disable DHCP, doesn't mean it becomes a switch automatically therefore it can still do routing functions without DHCP. All that means, is now any device connected to that router, will not obtain IP Address configuration automatically and would need to input those configurations manually on the systems connected to Router A.